# SQL/pivot Calculated fields, is this possible

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and Excel. I have an issue I'm having problems getting my head round surrounding how to get some fields calculated so  that it runs faster. I have a large data set that gets dropped into excel and stuck into a pivot table.

The table at it's simplest will contain a number of fields similar to the below.

Date    user    WorkType    Count   TotalTime

My issue is that I need to calculate an average in a particular way. Each user may have several worktypes on any given day. The formula I have is for each Date&User Sum(TotalTime)/Sum(Count) to get me the following

Date    user    Average

Currently I dump a select query into excel, apply formula to a column to get my averages then construct the pivot table using the personal details and the averages.

The calculation on over 20,000 rows however is about 5-7 minutes.

So my question is that possible to do that type of calculation in either SQL or Pivot table to cut down the processing time.   I'm not very confident with Pivot tables, and I'm considered fairly inexperienced at SQL compared to here. I can manage bits of this but pulling it all together with the conditions of matching Date and User is beyond me right now.

I could parse the recordset into an array to do my calculations that way before it gets written to the spreadsheet, but I just feel that there should be a better way to achieve the same end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Check out [ask] for tips on how to get the most out of the questions you ask here.  For example, in this case it's better if you start off by just trying something, then coming back if you have a more specific problem.  For your particular question, there's a good chance that SQL will be much faster for what you are trying to do, but you will probably benefit more from learning how to write it yourself so that you understand what it's doing.  You probably shouldn't use code you don't understand.  Search for how to use Aggregate functions and group by.

Comment: Thank you, I would much prefer to get help pointing me in the right direction than "here use this". I shall go delving as I think Group is perhaps the bit that I was missing.when I was trying to get my head round this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT          Raw_Data.ID, Raw_Data.fldDate, CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(second, 0, Raw_Data.TotalHandle)) / SUM(Raw_Data.[Call Count]), 0), 108) AS avgHandled
FROM            Raw_Data 
WHERE           (Raw_Data.fldDate BETWEEN '05-12-2016' AND '07-12-2016')
GROUP BY    Raw_Data.fldDate, Raw_Data.ID

For anyone interested here is the results of my searching.  Thank you for the help that pointed me in the right direction.  It seems quite clumsy with the conversions due to a time Datatype but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-calculated aggregates in SQL can go very wrong in an Excel Pivot.

Firstly, you can accidentally take an average of an average.

Secondly, once users start re-arranging the pivot you can get very strange sub-totals and totals.

Try to ensure you do all of your aggregation in one place. 
If possible try to use SQL with SSRS, you can base a report on a parameterised stored procedure. Consequently you push all of the hard work onto the SQL box, and you restrict users from pivoting things around improperly.